# Tag unknown s:property

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I'm coding with Eclipse. I have two lines in my code with a warning mark.

This warnings are :

```
unknown tag (s:property).
```

The two lines of code are below :

```
username : <s:property value="username" /><br/>
password : <s:property value="password" /><br/>
```

I don't understand, what's wrong? Is there someone to explain me what could be the problem ?

Comment: You should post the header of your XHTML

Comment: Did you use taglib directive to specify `s:` tags?

Comment: Without more information it's impossible to help.

Comment: ok i use the directive
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags"%> 
but there was an error
the correct directive is below
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
it was before my eyes... :-(
Thank you @Roman C

Comment: @jerome See explanation below.

Answer (score 4):

The Eclipse's JSP editor validates JSP files and if it finds errors in the code then red marks appears. You can also find errors in the problem view. Tags are validated according to TLD file that should be declared using JSP taglib directive. To use Struts tags in the code you should put the code below at the top of the page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

Read more about [JSP Tags](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/jsp-tags.html).

> The JSP TLD is included in the struts2-core-x.x.x.x.jar.

Answer (score 2):

ok i use the directive

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="struts-tags"%>
```

there was an error

the correct directive is below

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

it was before my eyes... :-(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you nsgocev 
i added a comment but i deleted it because it was not readable. I choose to answer on my own post but ok i understand it's not correct and not in the "spirit" of stackoverflow. Sorry ...

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question ... he had the wrong uri in the taglib declaration

Comment: @blank How it answers if asked for explanation but given only a code?